# Application gets too slow while drawing two bitmaps on a Canvas !

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I have two bitmap overlapped .The top bitmap is transparent and when user touch to screen i copy pixels from another bitmap to top bitmap.My goal is to give to users the feeling of erasing image with touching to see another image.However it is not working properly especially when user drags his finger too fast on the screen.I made a few tests and i beleive drawing bitmaps to the canvas every time cause the lag but i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a Canvas or Bitmap isn't redrawn until you wipe it yourself.  That means you just have change the alpha value of the pixels in the top Canvas/bitmap/thingy that are being "painted" rather than redrawing the entire canvas for every update.